# Why is the function called lseek(), not seek()?

Tags: c, standards

The C function for seeking in a file is called lseek(). Why ins't it called just seek()?

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: @andy256 `off_t` and if you want the 64 bit offset you use `lseek64`

Comment: @ratchetfreak er ... thanks. The question was for the OP's benefit, not mine :-)

Comment: My guess is that it is an evolutionary thing, just remains from the past where was a distinction between long and int.

Comment: From what @ysap suggests, lseek would be "long" seek, that is, it returns a long (64bit) offset.

Comment: RETURN VALUE
Upon successful completion, lseek() returns the resulting offset location as measured in bytes from the beginning of the file. Otherwise, a value of (off_t)-1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error. [Source][1]   
[1]: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/lseek.htm

Comment: The link @JNL gave says "BSD returns int", so it actually goes **against** the "l is for long" claim. Does anybody have a link to some document proving the claim?

Comment: The extra character was added to make up for the missing one in `creat()`.  (Actually, the L probably stands for logical.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears that the 'l' in lseek means 'long', to differentiate from an old seek function in version 2 of AT&T Unix. This is an anachronism before the off_t type was introduced.

Supporting references:

http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch03lev1sec6.html indicates:

> The character l in the name lseek means "long integer." Before the
>   introduction of the off_t data type, the offset argument and the
>   return value were long integers. lseek was introduced with Version 7
>   when long integers were added to C. (Similar functionality was
>   provided in Version 6 by the functions seek and tell.)

As noted at the foot of http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/lseek.2.html

> ```
>  A seek() function appeared in Version 2 AT&T UNIX, later renamed into
>  lseek() for ``long seek'' due to a larger offset argument type.
> ```

Comment: Intuition still works... :-)